# Adding a button to end of javascript quiz, using same style button as used in HTML files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I want to insert a button that will appear after a javascript quiz has been completed. I want the button to have the same style as the buttons used in my HTML files - styled from a CSS sheet. I'm not really experienced in JS.

End of quiz JS code:

```
function endQuiz() {
    $('#explanation').empty();
    $('#question-image').remove();
    $('#choice-block').empty();
    $('#pager').empty();
    $('#submitbutton').remove();
    $('#question').text("You got " + score + " out of " + quiz.length + " correct. Make sure you have a grip!");
    $(document.createElement('h2')).css({
        'text-align': 'center',
        'font-size': '4em'
    }).text(Math.round(score / quiz.length * 100) + 
'%').insertAfter('#question');
//button would go here

}
```

Can the button have a a href class in a js file?

I've tried and failed! thanks in advance.

Comment: What is an "a href class"? If you want to have consistent styling, just place your CSS in an external stylesheet and reference if from each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write the final button inside your html with the same style/class of the others button, giving it an id for reference through jQuery.

Then in the window.onload() or when your page is loaded call the jQuery .hide() function on the element.
        $('#your-button-id').hide()

When the quiz is is over show it with:
        $('#your-button-id').show()

Here docs about hide/show in jQuery: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 1):

For the button to have the same styles as the buttons in your html you just need to use the same CSS clases. For example if you have this css class:

```
.my-button {
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

then when creating the element you have to set the class attribute of your button in the js this way:

```
 var div = document.createElement('div');
 div.setAttribute('class', 'my-button');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the button to your html with the proper styling and then set its visibility to hidden. In your JavaScript code you can then change the attribute to show the button.

This link might be helpful:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp